# Multivariable equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got this multivariable equation from a friend last night and have not been able to solve it yet.

Solve for real values of x, y, z and w:
$ \sqrt{x} + 3\sqrt{y-1} + 5\sqrt{z-2} + 7\sqrt{w-3} = x+y+z+w+15$

I have tried to rewrite the equation as follows:

$ \sqrt{x} + 3\sqrt{y-1} + 5\sqrt{z-2} + 7\sqrt{w-3} = x+y+z+w+15 \\ \leftrightarrow $

$ \sqrt{x} + 3\sqrt{y-1} +5\sqrt{z-2} + 7\sqrt{w-3}=x+(y-1)+(z-2)+(w-3)+21\\ \leftrightarrow$

$ (\sqrt{x}-x)+ (3\sqrt{y-1}-(y-1))+(5\sqrt{z-2}-(z-2))+(7\sqrt{w-3}-(w-3))=21$

but now i'm stuck. Any thoughts on how I can continue? Maybe some completing the square on the brackets?

Comment: Let $\sqrt{x}=a$, $\sqrt{y-1}=b$, $\sqrt{z-2}=c$, and $\sqrt{w-3}=d$. You will be left with a quadratic equation describing a four-dimensional (hyper)ellipsoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem by continuing with your aforementioned idea which aimed to complete the squares in the equation obtained from some algebraic manipulation:
$ (\sqrt{x}-x)+ (3\sqrt{y-1}-(y-1))+(5\sqrt{z-2}-(z-2))+(7\sqrt{w-3}-(w-3))=21$.

If we rewrite every bracket to the form
$\frac{c^2}4-(\sqrt{a}-\frac{c}2)^2$, which is the completed square form of the expression $c\sqrt{a}-a$, we obtain:

$\frac{1}{4}-(\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{9}{4}-(\sqrt{y-1}-\frac{3}{2})^2+\frac{25}{4}-(\sqrt{z-2}-\frac{5}{2})^2+\frac{49}{4}-(\sqrt{w-3}-\frac{7}{2})^2=21$

$\leftrightarrow$

$\frac{84}{4}-(\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{2})^2-(\sqrt{y-1}-\frac{3}{2})^2-(\sqrt{z-2}-\frac{5}{2})^2-(\sqrt{w-3}-\frac{7}{2})^2=21$

but $\frac{84}{4}=21$

thus

$(\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{2})^2+(\sqrt{y-1}-\frac{3}{2})^2+(\sqrt{z-2}-\frac{5}{2})^2+(\sqrt{w-3}-\frac{7}{2})^2=0$.

This is true if and only if every square equals zero which satisfies by

$x=\frac{1}{4} \\ y=1+\frac{9}{4} \\ z=2+\frac{25}{4} \\ w=3+\frac{49}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

$\quad$ Let $\quad a=\sqrt x\geqslant0,\quad b=\sqrt{y-1}\geqslant0,\quad c=\sqrt{z-2}\geqslant0,\quad d=\sqrt{w-3}\geqslant0.\quad$ Then

$\quad a+3b+5c+7d=a^2+(b^2+1)+(c^2+2)+(d^2+3)+15=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+21.$

$\quad\Big(a-\tfrac12\Big)^2+\Big(b-\tfrac32\Big)^2+\Big(c-\tfrac52\Big)^2+\Big(d-\tfrac72\Big)^2=0.$ Can you take it from here ? :-)

Comment: Thank you! Your reference to a four-dimensional ellipsoid was informative.